# RxJava error handling The exception was not handled due to missing

Tags: android, rx-java

My problem is rxJava error The exception was not handled due to missing onError handler in the subscribe() method call. what is fix this?

```
compositeDisposable.add(backendApi.createEphemeralKey(params)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe { response ->
            try {
                val rawKey = response.string()
                keyUpdateListener.onKeyUpdate(rawKey)`
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                keyUpdateListener
                    .onKeyUpdateFailure(0, e.message ?: "")
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error suggests,

```
compositeDisposable.add(backendApi.createEphemeralKey(params)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe ({ response ->
                val rawKey = response.string()
                keyUpdateListener.onKeyUpdate(rawKey)
        }, // onError goes here as 2nd lambda parameter
        {e ->
             keyUpdateListener.onKeyUpdateFailure(0, e.message ?: "")
        })
)
```

This is basic error handling, please refer to docs
[Error Handling Operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators)

**WARNING**: Your question is too basic and is already answered, you will receive downvotes and duplicate flags.

Edit: I think the signature difference is because the Rx version you are using. anyway, the above should work with RxJava2 with your module targeting Java 8 at least to support lambdas.

Comment: onError method not exists

Comment: Check updated answer, and if you can provide rxjava version.